# Memory management while Loading assembly using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, memory-management, composite

All,

I am creating a component that uses composite pattern. The core component uses an XMl Meta data to define the composites (parts). at run time, the core component would use reflection to load the part assembly into the memory and call methods (e.g IPart.execute method).

Now my question is

1) will the (dynamic) memory that is occupied by the assembly that is loaded using reflection will be unloaded when i dispose the object or not.

2) if it does not unload and free the memory, is there is any way i can remove it from memory.

The reason of this question is, the component which i am building will be the core of my Business layer of an enterprise application which can be customized heavily.

Thanks
Albert Arul Prakash

Comment: When we use Regex microsoft says it creates a dynamic assemble and this assembly will not be garbage collected/unloaded from memory till application/appdomain is recycled.

When we load an assembly using reflection then does it create dynamic assembly.if yes then the objects would be always in memory and the usage of memory would not be optimized. 

this is my concern. free up resources can be achieved by proper defensive coding and IDIspose etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people load additional libraries via reflection (we could call these libraries "plugins") in another appdomain. For instance, see this article: http://adrianvintu.com/blogengine/post/Unloadable-plugins.aspx

This way you are protected from "evil" plugins as well as memory can be managed in such appdomain (when the appdomain unloads, the memory is freed up as well)

Comment: I never used app domain till now. My comment would be silly.

the composite is for methods (e.g Company.Insert) which can use more composite parts that is developed by consultants or the administrator of the system. So if i load the Company.Insert method and its parts to seperate appdomain, there is a possibility of having more number of App domains in memory at any given time. Does that not create performance issue?.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that can consume memory in a plugin/module.   Grossly speaking, these are code (loading the assembly into your process space consumes memory), and objects (creating an instance of something consumes memory).

> will the (dynamic) memory that is occupied by the assembly that is loaded using reflection will be unloaded when i dispose the object or not.

Calling `Dispose` on `IDisposable` doesn't do anything to the object as far as memory is concerned.  It might free resources that the object uses (e.g. if you close a file, it will get rid of open file handles), but it won't free the object itself.  `IDisposable` isn't a magic memory-freeing function - it is just a method on an interface that lets an object know that it should get rid of resources that it owns.

To free the object itself, you must get rid of all references to it (possibly set them to null, or let them fall off your program's stack), and the garbage collector must eventually run to reclaim that memory.

> if it does not unload and free the memory, is there is any way i can remove it from memory.

If you are only concerned about resources like GUI and file handles, make sure you call `Dispose`.  You should always do this :)

If you are concerned about object memory, just let the GC do its work.  Don't pester it to, either.  Let it run on its own.

If you are concerned about code memory, you must unload the `AppDomain` that the code is in.  If this is your default `AppDomain` then you can't unload it without quitting your program.  Instead, you should load that plugin in a sub `AppDomain` that you created at runtime.  You can then get the code out of your process space by unloading the sub `AppDomain`.

See [naivists' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007061/memory-management-while-loading-assembly-using-reflection/8007115#8007115) for information on how to use a sub `AppDomain`.